# What chapter in the manga corresponds to Episode 24, the Season two finale?

Tags: manga, anime, reincarnated-as-a-slime

The anime "*[That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37430/Tensei_shitara_Slime_Datta_Ken)*" was adapted from a [manga of the same name](https://tensura.fandom.com/wiki/Manga).

Episode 24 is the Season two finale. **What chapter of the manga corresponds to this episode of the anime?**

It's very close to the death of Claymon (after Rimuru finally defeats him) as well as being close to when they officially make the group's new name “*Octagram*”, with that also being the name of the final episode.

Comment: I've not read the manga, but the wiki has a 'first appearance' section that suggests that the [first appearance of the octagram](https://tensura.fandom.com/wiki/Octagram) was as follows;  Web Novel (Chapter 83: *Eight Star Demon Lords*), Light Novel (Volume 6: *The Octagram Soars Brightly*), **Manga (Chapter 86: *Octagram Demon Lords*)**

Answer (score 1):

Season 2, Episode 24 of the anime corresponds to Chapters 85 and 86 of the manga.

- [Chapter 85](https://tensura.fandom.com/wiki/In_a_Holy_Place) (*In a Holy Place*) deals with Rimuru's fight with Clayman.
- [Chapter 86](https://tensura.fandom.com/wiki/The_Octagram) (*Octagram Demon Lords*) largely deals with the
  aftermath as the Council of Ten Demon Lords reconvenes.

These novels were collected together in [Volume 19](https://tensura.fandom.com/wiki/Manga_Volume_19)